# Separating float integral and fractional

Tags: c, floating-point

I am trying to separate a float into it's integral and fractal parts. My method works fine for some values, but does not when I encounter a value that has a longer decimal representation.

```
fractalValue = modf(value, &z);
l_integral = z;
l_fractal = fractalValue * 1000.0;
```

For example, when I have value = 13.1800, this works fine.

But when value = 2.24213798933e-36 the program fails.
In this instance, the modf function returns 2.24213798933e-36 fractalValue variable, and 0 to z.

Comment: `double l_integral = (int) value; double l_fractal = value - l_integral;`? Or use `floor` instead of casting to get the integer part.

Comment: 2.24213798933e-36 is less than 1, so its integer part is 0 and the fraction part is 2.24213798933e-36. The results you got, 0 and 2.24213798933e-36, were correct. What did you expect instead and why?

Comment: if i do this, l_integral get the value 0. and l_fractal gets 2.24213798933e-36

Comment: Well for a value less than `1` (but larger than `0`) that makes sense.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: No, converting to `int` will overflow in some cases and not get anything different from `modf` when it does not. Using `floor` will get a wrong result for negative numbers (that are not integers).

Comment: Use `modfl` and `long double` mayhaps? If the system supports those.

Comment: Integral in the second example has to be zero as the value is far below `1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2.24213798933e-36` is `0.00000000000000000000000000000000224213798933` (may be off by one or two zeros, but you should get the idea).  The integral portion of the value *is `0`*, and the fractional portion is effectively `0`, and multiplying "effectively `0`" by `1000.0` leaves you with "effectively `0`".

You are getting entirely expected results.  Just because you have a non-zero leading digit doesn’t mean the integer portion of the value isn’t `0`, it just means you have a *normalized* value (i.e, written such that there’s a single non-zero digit to the left of the decimal).  `1.23e-3` is the normalized form of `0.00123` - your code would return `0` and `1.23`.

Comment: maybe he wants strip the expotential part

Answer (score -1):

You want to get the the parts from the exponent display form so for 2.435343454e36 it will be `2` and `0.435343454`

If yes toy need to "normalize" your number (remove the `e` part). Then you can use your formulas to get the number parts

```
double remove_e(double val)
{
    int sign = val < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    if(val != 0.0)
    {
        val *= sign;
        double logten = log10(val);
        val /= pow(10, ceil(logten)-1);
    }
    return sign * val;
}

int main(void)
{
    double x = 2.34546465;

    printf("%e -> %f\n", x, remove_e(x));
    x = 0.0;
    printf("%e -> %f\n", x, remove_e(x));
    x = 2.34546465e-36;
    printf("%e -> %f\n", x, remove_e(x));
    x = 2.34546465e36;
    printf("%e -> %f\n", x, remove_e(x));
    x = -0.0;
    printf("%e -> %f\n", x, remove_e(x));
    x = -2.34546465e-36;
    printf("%e -> %f\n", x, remove_e(x));
    x = -2.34546465e36;
    printf("%e -> %f\n", x, remove_e(x));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MevdfP